# Function to create a non equally spaced array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create an array with the form `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...]`. Not always with that spacing between numbers.

Is there a `linspace`/`arange` type function which allows me to create vector of non equally spaced numbers?

Thanks

Comment: In your case, seems like you want `[2]**np.arange(6)`

Comment: I think you need to better define your requirements. "non-equally spaced numbers" is very vague. @RafaelC offers a solid solution. But you way have further requirements we are not aware of.

Comment: You need specifically a python (numpy) function? AAny problem with this way: `[2**i for i in range(6)]`

Comment: @rahlf23 It is vague on purpose. I'm looking for a flexible function (if it exist). And as I stated in my question, it will not always have the same spacing.

Comment: @Hamidreza I'm aware that I can build my own function, nut I'm new to numpy and I want to know if there's a predefined tool for this. Maybe the answer is that there's none and that I must build my own.

Comment: I think so, especially when "the spacing is not the same".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is also `logspace` and `geomspace` in NumPy.

`np.geomspace(1,32,6)` gives you `array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  8., 16., 32.])`